# Coherence theorem for monoidal categories in string diagram calculus

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monoidal-categories

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3347v1.pdf) paper Theorem 3.1 is a coherence theorem for monoidal categories in the string diagram calculus.

I don't mind taking this theorem for granted for now, but I'm not quite sure whether I really understand it: the statement sounds *too easy*, so much that I'm quite unsure if I'd be using it right.

The Caveat 3.2. following the theorem confuses me even more.

> Where can I find a more comprehensive / rigorous explanation of the coherence theorem for monoidal categories using string diagrams?

Comment: It seems like Selinger documents this very thoroughly, with the two original citations. What else do you need? The result is simply not known for non-recumbent isotopies.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Oh. It seems I missed the citations. I'll be looking at those then too. Thank you!